# Alter Open Graph Stories in Facebook Sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I am following the sample from
[facebook reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android) for creating Open graph content.
It works fine. I have pasted the screen shot of the post. The post is says that "James Jack read Puzzle Game - Ball Mania on Puzzle Game - Ball Mania."  Actually it has to be like "James Jack played Puzzle Game - Ball Mania"

How to achieve it ? Please advice

### Code

[image]
[image: Facebook Post]

Comment: Books are read, not “played”. If you want your user to play something, then chose a different object type – other than `books.book` – and a different action to begin with.

Comment: You will need to create a custom action type for `play`. You can look at the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom#actions